# systemd - get dropbear to only look at openvpn interface

Tags: ssh, systemd

I am trying to configure dropbear to do the following.

1) Only listen on port 22 of the tun0 interface (made by openvpn service).
2) Only use public key authorization.

I see that dropbear.socket is able to look at port 22.  But how do I have it only look at an openvpn iface (eg tun0)?

I've tried "BindToDevice" on the dropbear.socket systemd file - but I'm getting a chicken and egg issue where dropbear socket is needed to show the network is up, but openvpn needs the network up to start to create the tun0 device.

Is there a better way to configure dropbear to only look at a particular interface?

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with the same problem myself, I've come up with two solutions.  The first is a bit clumsy, but allows the use of `BindToDevice`.  It requires setting `DefaultDependencies=no` and then replicating the [default dependencies](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#Default%20Dependencies), with the exception of the `Before=sockets.target` dependency.  The `.socket` file might look like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dropbear Activation Socket
DefaultDependencies=no
After=sysinit.target
Requires=sysinit.target
Before=shutdown.service
Conflicts=shutdown.service
Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
After=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device

[Socket]
ListenStream=:22
BindToDevice=tun0
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note also that the for `WantedBy=` I used `multi-user.target` and not `sockets.target`.

However, there is another solution that is simpler if your use case permits specifying the `tun0` IP address in the `.socket` file.  To accomplish this, specify the IP address in the `ListenStream` directive and use [`FreeBind=yes`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#FreeBind=) instead of `BindToDevice=tun0`.  The resulting `.socket` file might look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dropbear Activation Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=<tun0 IP address>:22
FreeBind=yes
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```